# Poor Performance on Outer Join Timestamp Range Comparisons (Gap-Filling Time Series Data)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some time-series data (1.5 million rows currently). I am filling in some time gaps in my query using the generate_series method.

Imagine the following data that has a gap between 10 AM and 1 PM....

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| time  | category | value |
+-------+----------+-------+
| 8  AM |        1 |   100 |
| 9  AM |        1 |   200 |
| 10 AM |        1 |   300 |
| 1  PM |        1 |   100 |
| 2  PM |        1 |   500 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

I need my query results to fill in any gaps with the last known value for the series. Such as the following....

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| time  | category | value |
+-------+----------+-------+
| 8  AM |        1 |   100 |
| 9  AM |        1 |   200 |
| 10 AM |        1 |   300 |
| 11 AM |        1 |   300 | (Gap filled with last known value)
| 12 PM |        1 |   300 | (Gap filled with last known value)
| 1  PM |        1 |   100 |
| 2  PM |        1 |   500 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

I have a query that does this, but it's really slow (~5 secs in thesimplified example below). I'm hoping someone can show me a better/faster way?
In my case, my data is by the minute. So I fill in the gaps on 1-minute increments. I use the lead/window function to determine what the NEXT timestamp is for each row so I know which generated gap fillers will use that value.

Please see example below....

**Generate test data**
(create data for every minute for a year, with a 1 hour gap two hours ago)

```
create table mydata as
with a as
(
    select 
        date_time
    from 
        generate_series(date_trunc('minute', now())::timestamp - '1 year':: interval, date_trunc('minute', now()::timestamp - '2 hours'::interval), interval '1 minute') as date_time 
    union
    select 
        date_time
    from 
        generate_series(date_trunc('minute', now())::timestamp - '1 hour':: interval, date_trunc('minute', now()::timestamp ), interval '1 minute') as date_time 
),
b as
(
    select category from generate_series(1,10,1) as category
)
select
    a.*,
    b.*,
    round(random() * 100)::integer as value
from
    a 
cross join 
    b
;

create index myindex1 on mydata (category, date_time);
create index myindex2 on mydata (date_time);
```

**Query the data to get all category=5 data for the last 5 days (with gaps filled)**

```
with a as
(
    select 
        mydata.*,
        lead(mydata.date_time) over (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date_time asc) as next_date_time
    from 
        mydata
    where 
        category = 5 
    and
        date_time between now() - '5 days'::interval and now()
),
b as
(
     SELECT generated_time::timestamp without time zone FROM generate_series(date_trunc('minute', now()) - '5 days'::interval, date_trunc('minute', now()), interval '1 minute') as generated_time
)
select
    b.generated_time as date_time,
    a.category,
    a.value
from
    b
left join
    a
on
    b.generated_time >= a.date_time and b.generated_time < a.next_date_time
order by
    b.generated_time desc
;
```

This query functions perfectly. Sample results...

```
+---------------------+----------+-------+
|   date_time         | category | value |
+---------------------+----------+-------+
| 2018-07-06 12:17:00 | 5        | 13    |
| 2018-07-06 12:16:00 | 5        | 17    | (gap filled)
| 2018-07-06 12:15:00 | 5        | 17    | (gap filled)
| ...                 | ...      | ...   | (gap filled)
| 2018-07-06 11:18:00 | 5        | 17    | (gap filled)
| 2018-07-06 11:17:00 | 5        | 17    |
| 2018-07-06 11:16:00 | 5        | 62    |
+---------------------+----------+-------+
```

However, this part kills performance...

```
b.generated_time >= a.date_time and b.generated_time < a.next_date_time
```

If I just do something like..

```
b.generated_time = a.next_date_time
```

Then it's very fast, but of course, incorrect results. It really doesn't like me doing an 'and', OR, greaterThan or lessThan. I thought that maybe it was because I was comparing to next_date_time which is generated on-the-fly and not indexed. But I even tried materializing that data into a table with an index first, performance was roughly the same.
I added the timescaledb extension tag to this post in case they have some built-in functionality to assist with this.

**The 'explain' results**

```
Sort  (cost=268537.46..270431.35 rows=757556 width=16)
  Sort Key: b.generated_time DESC
  CTE a
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.44..11057.66 rows=6818 width=24)
          ->  Index Scan using myindex1 on mydata  (cost=0.44..10938.35 rows=6818 width=16)
                Index Cond: ((category = 5) AND (date_time >= (now() - '5 days'::interval)) AND (date_time <= now()))
  CTE b
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series generated_time  (cost=0.02..12.52 rows=1000 width=8)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..170538.18 rows=757556 width=16)
        Join Filter: ((b.generated_time >= a.date_time) AND (b.generated_time < a.next_date_time))
        ->  CTE Scan on b  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=8)
        ->  CTE Scan on a  (cost=0.00..136.36 rows=6818 width=24)
```

I'm using Postgres 10.4. Any suggestions on how to make this faster?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I going to 'partially' answer my own question. I did find a way to accomplish what I want that performs MUCH better (sub-second). However, it is not as intuitive/readable and would really like to know how to make my first method faster. Just for the sake of knowledge, I really want to know what I was doing wrong.

Anyway, the following method seems to work. I calculate the number of minutes between each row, then just generate a series of rows with the same data but with 1 minute increments that number of times.

I'll give this a few days. If nobody comes up with a fix (or a better way) for the first method, then I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

```
select 
    generate_series(date_time, date_time + (((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (lead(mydata.date_time) over w - date_time)) / 60)-1) || 'minutes')::interval, interval '1 minute') as date_time,
    category,
    value
from 
    mydata
where 
    category = 5 
and
    date_time between now() - '5 days'::interval and now()
window w as (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY date_time asc) 
order by
    mydata.date_time desc
```